# Using OR statement in sequelize where query

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have some issue using or statement is sequelize. 
Below is the code I have been able to come up with:

```
UserExist(req, res) {
const field = req.body.username || req.body.email;
const getFieldName = field === req.body.username ? 'username' : 'email';
return User
  .findOne({ where: {
    $or: [
      {
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username
      }
    ]
  }
  })
  .then((user) => {
    if (user) {
      res.status(200).send({ message: `${getFieldName} already exist` });
    }
  })
  .catch(() => res.status(404).send({ message: '' }));
```

}

Instead of executing the OR statment it only selects * from Users

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [sequelize documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators)

you should give different where conditions as different element of `$or` array

Please try this:

```
$or: [
  {
    email: req.body.email
  },
  {
    username: req.body.username
  }
]
```